# Twilio outbound call didn't wait the agent to answer and add client to call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

Here is the logic :

a client is filling a quiz and once he finished twilio will call one of the customer agent using webhook then add the client to the call using twiml Dial. I'm sending the client number as a parameter to the twiml file it look like this https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?clientnumber=+1234567890

And here is my twiml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial answerOnBridge="true">
  <Number>
    {{clientnumber}} 
  </Number> 
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem here is that twilio calls both the agent and the customer at the same time but what I need is to call the agent first then not call the customer until the agent answer the phone.